# Ruby: JSON result for several depending tables

Tags: ruby, json, rest

I am using working with the ruby blog example. So I have the tables posts, comments and tags. The posts table is related 1 to many comments and tags. This works great. 
- The point I don't get is how to get a single JSON response for a post at his depending records (tags and comments)? 
- How is the URL format to get all comments of the first post?

Thanks a lot, 
  Vanessa

Answer (score 0):

You would join the posts table with the comments table on post_id.  Something like this:

```
 Select comments from comments, posts where posts.post_id = <id of post you want comments of> and posts.id = comments.post_id
```